# How to secure API (private key) for mobile apps

Tags: ios, web-services, api, security, key

I am building a web service that has to be only accessible for iOS apps. 
In the future I want to expand to a mobile website to make my service also available for other mobile operating systems.

Now, I have everything working through an API. my users can register, search companies, order products from those companies and track their orders. It's not active yet, but it's working..

I am facing one major problem: How to secure this?

For the last few days I have stopped coding and I have constantly been busy with searching the web, StackOverflow and Information Security for how to do this. I have found that the way amazon secures their API would be the best solution for me. The way amazon secures it's service is explained [here](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/). I have tweaked it a little bit for my service:

1. User registers and gets private API key + public (identification) key
2. User enters credentials and taps "log in". App creates hash out of the variables + private key. App sends variables + time stamp + hash + public key to API
3. API looks up public key in database, finds private key belonging to that public key (if public key is valid). The API then creates hash the same way as the app did. If the hashes are the same, the request (log in in this case) is executed.

This way of securing a service makes sense to me, and I can code most of it. but I have a major problem and I can not find any solution to it:

- The user gets a public & private API key when an account is created. The public key can be sent from the server to the user device, because that is not necessarily a secret. Since the private API key can ***never*** be sent over the wire, **how on earth can I make sure that an account logged in on a user's device knows the private API key that is created on the server?**

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?? any help would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 6):

I think you have over complicated your authentication scheme. 
I would suggest using a widely used protocol like oauth2 to secure your API - http://oauth.net/2/.
There are a lot of client libraries and a lot of server-side plugins that support and implement it, and makes it easy to integrate into your application.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I solved the same problem and why I think your actual problem is different than the one you think:

The way Amazon does it makes sense, is secure, and way easier to implement than oAuth so I'm not sure why everyone suggests using it. I use the Amazon method which goes like this:

1. User registers to use the API. We make sure to generate a public key, secret key, and save a contact email, a role (our roles are "admin" and "user") and then set the API user's `status` to active. This allows us to manage role based permissions on the server (rate limiting, access control, etc) and deactivate an account at any time
2. We **send the client ID and secret key back to the client**. There's just no way around this so you make it as secure as possible by:

   - Only sending the token once. If the user forgets their token they need to register a new API client
   - Make sure **all requests are made over HTTPS**, no exceptions - this makes it so that any sniffed traffic is encrypted and an attacker only has one shot to intercept
   - *Encrypt* the token in the database. Don't hash it because it needs to be reversible. If you securely store your encryption key and generate a new random IV (initialization vector) when encrypting with say AES-256, then an attacker will not be able to retrieve client secret keys (in theory, if you secure that key properly but even if not it buys you some time to deactivate compromised client tokens). You send the plain text token to the client when its generated but encrypt it *before* it hits the database.
3. When a client makes a request they send a header and a signed request. On your server you find the encrypted token associated with the client ID, decrypt it, then compute the signature and compare it to what was sent. If your computed signature and theirs match then you let the request proceed.

Like I said, there's no way around sending the private token to the client but the good thing is that you only do it a single time and it should be over SSL anyway.

**The problem you're missing is how to protect that token on the device itself.** That's another problem that I haven't seen any solutions for.

The only viable options for both these cases are:

1. You generate a private token once per client on the server and only send it to the client a single time (no reminders, only total resets like with Amazon)
2. You really can't do anything but store the token on the device itself.

One measure we came up with for securing the token on the device is to actually rotate tokens periodically. So for example, you have the token either stored on the device for each user or hardcoded into the app. Every so often you require a new token for the device. If you have a hard coded token then you update the app with a new hard coded token and when the user updates through their app store they'll get the new token automatically. You then revoke all the tokens that are X days old and require any stragglers to update the app. The other option if each client is given a unique token upon logging in/registering is to also expire the token and then automatically log them out the next time they use the app. Upon logging back in you generate and send them a new token valid for X days.

In the end, these are a few problems that are common and I don't think solved yet at least for the method of authentication you're using. So the best thing you could really do is accept the small risk associated with sending and storing the token and put your energy into making the API secure.

Comment: In your second sentence you are questioning use of OAuth, then you discover the only problem is how to protect token on the device itself where OAuth is made as solution for.

Answer (score 2):

### YES, IT'S PUBLIC

> This way of securing a service makes sense to me, and I can code most of it. but I have a major problem and I can not find any solution to it:
>
> The user gets a public & private API key when an account is created. The public key can be sent from the server to the user device, because that is not necessarily a secret. Since the private API key can never be sent over the wire, how on earth can I make sure that an account logged in on a user's device knows the private API key that is created on the server?

As you well said the private key can never be sent over the wire in whatever way anyone deems secure (thinking of an https connection using certificate pining, that can be bypassed), because from the moment you do it it must be considered as belonging to the public domain, not as it's name convey, private. Shipping it with mobile app code in whatever form deemed secure is also making the private key indeed a public one. Storing it in the encrypted store of the mobile device doesn't also secure it from leaking, because reverse engineer techniques exist to reverse engineer a mobile app statically or at runtime.

### REVERSE ENGINEERING

Contrary of what many think reverse engineering is not that hard, and a lot of open source tools exist to help us in the process. For example, some of the most popeular reverse engineering tools that can be used in stand-alone mode or combined, are this ones (many more exist):

[MobSF - Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF)

> Mobile Security Framework is an automated, all-in-one mobile application (Android/iOS/Windows) pen-testing framework capable of performing static analysis, dynamic analysis, malware analysis and web API testing.

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/):

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

[mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/)

> An interactive TLS-capable intercepting HTTP proxy for penetration testers and software developers.

I wrote several articles on how to use the above tools to extract API keys or bypass certificate pinning, for example:

[How to Extract an API key from a Mobile App with Static Binary Analysis](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-extract-an-api-key-from-a-mobile-app-with-static-binary-analysis):

> The range of open source tools available for reverse engineering is huge, and we really can't scratch the surface of this topic in this article, but instead we will focus in using the [Mobile Security Framework(MobSF)](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) to demonstrate how to reverse engineer the APK of our mobile app. MobSF is a collection of open source tools that present their results in an attractive dashboard, but the same tools used under the hood within MobSF and elsewhere can be used individually to achieve the same results.
>
> During this article we will use the [Android Hide Secrets](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) research repository that is a dummy mobile app with API keys hidden using several different techniques.

[Steal that Api Key with a Man in the Middle Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack):

> In order to help to demonstrate how to steal an API key, I have built and released in Github the [Currency Converter Demo](https://github.com/approov/currency-converter-demo/tree/0.1.1) app for Android, which uses the same [JNI/NDK](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni) technique we used in the earlier [Android Hide Secrets](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/src/main/java/com/criticalblue/androidhidesecrets/MainActivity.java#L37-L41) app to [hide the API key](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/src/main/cpp/api_key.h.example).
>
> So, in this article you will learn how to setup and run a MitM attack to intercept https traffic in a mobile device under your control, so that you can steal the API key. Finally, you will see at a high level how MitM attacks can be mitigated.

[Bypassing Certificate Pinning](https://blog.approov.io/bypassing-certificate-pinning)

> In this article you will learn how to repackage a mobile app in order to make it trust custom ssl certificates. This will allow us to bypass certificate pinning.

All this can be done without the need to be a security expert, even non-developers will be able to follow online tutorials to hack a mobile app.

So, in the end of the day the motivation (financial or others) to hack your mobile app will be the one dictating how much effort an attacker will want to put on it, thus you need to put as many obstacles (security defences) in his way as possible, even the ones that you know that can be bypassed.

### Possible Solutions

> Does anybody know how to solve this problem?? any help would be highly appreciated!!

I recommend you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605789/6454622) I gave to the question *How to secure an API REST for mobile app?*, especially the sections "The difference between **what** and **who** is accessing the API server", *Hardening and Shielding the Mobile App*, *Securing the API Server* and *A Possible Better Solution*.

You will find that the solution best fitted to solve your problem will be the Mobile App Attestation that will allow your API server to know with a very high degree of confidence that **what** is making the request is indeed a genuine and untampered version of your mobile app.

#### Do You Want To Go The Extra Mile?

In any response to a security question I always like to reference the excellent work from the OWASP foundation.

#### For APIS

[OWASP API Security Top 10](https://github.com/OWASP/API-Security)

> The OWASP API Security Project seeks to provide value to software developers and security assessors by underscoring the potential risks in insecure APIs, and illustrating how these risks may be mitigated. In order to facilitate this goal, the OWASP API Security Project will create and maintain a Top 10 API Security Risks document, as well as a documentation portal for best practices when creating or assessing APIs.

#### For Mobile Apps

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

[OWASP - Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg):

> The Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG) is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security development, testing and reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1):

As Rotem Hermon suggest i would implement Oauth2 as well.

About the "how on earth can I make sure that an account logged in on a user's device knows the private API key that is created on the server?" question, (in a very abstract level) the server confirms that the client knows the private key trough a signature calculation of the private key.

A silly abstracted example:

Server has the private clients key ("Z")
Client has his private key ("Z")

They both also knows their public key ("Y")

Client hashes the request to the resource ("A") and his private and public key to sign the request with a function like this  `signMyRequest(request,publicKey,privateKey)`

In this example would be `signMyRequest("A","Y","Z")`

Public Key would comply the role of 'username' and private key would comply the role of 'password'. The difference is that you dont pass it to the server, AWS just does a calculation over the private key. Look up for AWS Signature V4 for more information:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

Hope that helps and take it only as an abstract example of the functionality.

Leaving authentication and authorization aside you should also concern for common security weakness such as SQL Injection, XSS, and such since its also a Web Application and most of the common security weakness applies.

Comment: Hi Igarr, thank you for your response! I think I misformulated my question. you are assuming that both the server side AND client already know the keys. what I meant to ask about is: When an account is made, the API should generate a private key and store that key in my database with the beloning account. but at that point the client doesn't know the private key yet. How can I make sure that the client side knows the private key that is stored in the database, without sending it over the wire?

Comment: Oh my bad. Well you have to send it somehow as well. Even Amazon Web Services send it trough his website at least once by a secure channel using SSL.

If you wanna avoid this, you could implement a RSA Token solution (secure but expensive), let the user set his private key (insecure but easy to implement) or send it using another channel such as Email or SMS.

Comment: ah, so the rule that a private key should never be sent anywhere is not that strict.. thank you! I will look into Oauth2 as well ;)

Comment: Shouldn't be sent on every transaction, it has to be sent at least once. I think i'll go for the last option by sending the private key trough another mean, that's the general recommendation so in case someone hacks a developers account  it wont have his private key as well. But i think oauth2 will make you save a lot of time and effort in this case :)