# How to protect CODE TAMPERING in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, security

I'm new to Flutter and I'm creating an app in Flutter.
Currently I'm going through some of the security points. One of which is "Code Tampering".

How to protect the app from code tampering & code injection?
In Native Android, we use to check verify the Release key Signature so that we can avoid code tampering.
Is there any plugin or any way to do the same in Flutter?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a free RASP (runtime App self-protection) SDK for Flutter that helps to prevent app Tampering, running with Debugger/Emulator/Hooking frameworks, and also Root/JB detection.

https://pub.dev/packages/freerasp

*Disclaimer. I am a co-founder of this product so any critics and feedbacks are welcome. :)*

NB: you can get inspired by this thread as well: [How to protect Flutter app from reverse engineering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527430/how-to-protect-flutter-app-from-reverse-engineering/64543495)

Comment: Hi  @sergey-y, I have question about freerasp-flutter lib,
Did you guys using this on any production app? Or do you know anyone using on production this lib?

Comment: @SergeyY. then how to use it as example of it on flutter always return secured when mobile is rooted

Comment: @SergeyY. Can you give me a right example to use it ?

Comment: @AhmedRaafat, if you found a combination of rooting tool and hider on some Android  version that is not detected,  would you please share it with the team via info (at) Talsec.app. I am the team member and I would appreciate this a lot.  Thank you.

Comment: FreeRASP is used by many apps in prod.  Commercial version of it is more suitable for prod usage of course.  It comes with Appicrypt and other  security hardening features.