# Securing API Keys In Flutter But How?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to  Secure my API Key  and I don't want to hardcode them in code like in image given below because anyone can decomplile app & get my secret key  [image]

is there ant Better Way to  do this

Comment: Read this answser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527430/how-to-protect-flutter-app-from-reverse-engineering/64543495#64543495 very intersting

Comment: You can check out this article [How to Store API Keys in Flutter: --dart-define vs .env files](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-api-keys-dart-define-env-files/) from Andrea

Answer (score 0):

In order to not expose the API key client side, you need a backend solution. Firebase cloud functions work well with Flutter. You call your backend function which uses the newsapi and returns the results back to Flutter.

Comment: what if i dont want to use firebase ?? any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [envied](https://pub.dev/packages/envied) and use @EnviedField(obfuscate: true) to encrypt your keys