# I am create a paymente gateway application in Flutter, I need to secure the my API urls and KEYS

Tags: flutter, dart

How I can secure my API URLs and keys from hackers and reverse engineering in the flutter.
Which is the best way to secure the app in flutter development.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to protect Flutter app from reverse engineering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527430/how-to-protect-flutter-app-from-reverse-engineering)

Comment: No, It's for reverse enginnering

Comment: You asked in your question about revise engineering.... and hackers too will get hold to your API urls and keys inside the app by reverse engineering only!