# The Keys are getting leaked in the Strings.xml file. Is there any way to store the keys in some other files and use the values in Strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml, react-native, security, code-push

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">Test App</string>
  <string 
    moduleConfig="true" 
    name="CodePushDeploymentKey">
    PUT-YOUR-DEPLOYMENT-KEY-HERE
  </string>
</resources>
```

This is the sample code for the String.xml file where I am storing the key for my React Native app for CodePush.

When I run the app through Vulnerability test, it showed that the keys are getting leaked from the Strings.xml file. So is there any other way to store the files rather than in Strings.xml ? Or how can we prevent the key values from getting leaked from Strings.xml file ?

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android#secrets-in-resource-files

Comment: Store the names of the keys in the configuration files and not the actual keys.  Keys are normal transferred in an encrypted certificate and then the keys are loaded into the user account.  The user account is protected so the keys are not obtainable.

Answer (score 0):

Storing it in an **.env** file will ensure reliability.

For more information.

[Answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916923/react-native-storing-api-key)