# Avoiding phishing attacks in native mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am currently designing a native app which will have a simple username / password login. On a valid authentication, the backend server is issuing a JWT access token and refresh token which are eventually used throughout subsequent API calls.

My concern is that using such an approach, my app can be prone to phishing whereby a hacker can decompile and recompile my app with malicious interceptors.

In order to overcome this, I was thinking of designing my Login API, so that rather than having an `accessToken` and a `refreshToken` in the payload response of the API, the Login API will issue a 301 Redirect on `myapp://some-path?accessToken=X&refreshToken=Y`. This will ensure that if a phishing app is calling my APIs, the `accessToken` and the `refreshToken` are sent to the original APP.

Is this a correct approach? If not, which design would be suggested?

Answer (score 2):

How would that help?  If I'm going into your app to hack and recompile, I'll be taking over the entire app.  I won't leave a copy of the old version, I'm just going to replace the urls.  So when you redirect to myapp://somepath, it'll be redirecting to the same hacked app.

Secondly,  how would a redirect do anything?  Making an HTTP request doesn't cause an app to be launched on the client.  It causes the HTTP request to return a HTTPResponse object with a response code of 301.  So your redirect URL wouldn't be launched anyway.

Third, that's already too late.  By the time you have an access and refresh token, you've logged in.  That means the hacked app has your password and credentials. 2FA may help here a bit to make it harder to attack, but only if its time based, and even then it just reduces the window.

If a user is installing a hacked version of your app and is willing to sign into it, you've already lost.

Comment: Further, the redirect to an app url is actually less secure. Any app can declare support for any url scheme, and which one ios will deliver to isn't defined, so an "attacker" could add your url scheme to their app and they may get your token response if ios decides to open their app instead of yours. Of course, the user would see that the wrong app is opening and the attacker has to somehow get your user to install their "Trojan horse" app. As Gabe says, Token interception probably isn't a very big risk here since it requires actions on the part of the user that seem unlikely

Comment: Thanks for your insight in this matter. So how would you suggest that I identify the WHAT is accessing my APIs? Researched a bit on this matter and I can't seem to find a suitable solution how I can be sure that my APIs are being called from the rightful APP.

Comment: @cgval You can't.  Really, there's no way to know that can't be hacked around.  You can assure that the user is authorized via shared secret (password, basically) that comes from data outside the app.  There's no way to be sure that the app being used is authorized, because any secret being shared is part of the app and can be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

### YOUR PROBLEM

> I am currently designing a native app which will have a simple username / password login. On a valid authentication, the backend server is issuing a JWT access token and refresh token which are eventually used throughout subsequent API calls.

You need to bear in mind that any secret that leaves the backend or is stored inside a mobile app is no longer a secret, instead it's a public thing, even if you are using TLS (can be intercepted in some scenarios) and Certificate pinning (can be bypassed in some circunstances), because an attacker can reverse engineer your mobile app via a plethora of open source tools and techniques, one of them being static decompilation as you mention:

> My concern is that using such an approach, my app can be prone to phishing whereby a hacker can decompile and recompile my app with malicious interceptors.

Once it's decompiled the attacker can do whatever he wants with your code, not just adding interceptors. It's well known problem that the Google Play store is full of [cloned](https://techviral.net/best-clone-apps-for-android/) and repackaged apps that will use the same backend as the genuine app. You even have a repo [RePack: A repository of repackaged Android apps](https://github.com/serval-snt-uni-lu/RePack), that illustrates the problem:

> RePack is a repository of over 15,000 repackaged Android app pairs collected from AndroZoo. The SHA256 of the apps are available in the repackaging_pairs.txt file. The actual APKs are available in the AndroZoo dataset, which can be downloaded by giving a SHA256 as input. Please following this page to learn how to download apps from AndroZoo.

When repackaged the apps can be used to simply add ads to it and act as a fake app to your service where the profits will go to the attacker, or can be used to distribute malware and/or spy on users as seen in the article [700,000 malicious Android apps found in Google Play store last year](https://www.which.co.uk/news/2018/02/700000-malicious-android-apps-found-in-google-play-store-last-year/):

> Google has confirmed that it had to remove nearly 700,000 potentially malicious apps from the Google Play store in 2017 – an increase of 70% from the previous year.

#### Reverse Engineering

The truth is that anything running in the client side can be reverse engineered
easily by an attacker on a device he controls.

When reverse engineering a mobile app an attacker first step may be to perform a static binary analysis to extract all static secrets and to identify attack vectors, and you can see how in my article
[How to Extract an API key from a Mobile App with Static Binary Analysis](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-extract-an-api-key-from-a-mobile-app-with-static-binary-analysis):

> The range of open source tools available for reverse engineering is huge, and we really can't scratch the surface of this topic in this article, but instead we will focus in using the [Mobile Security Framework(MobSF)](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) to demonstrate how to reverse engineer the APK of our mobile app. MobSF is a collection of open source tools that present their results in an attractive dashboard, but the same tools used under the hood within MobSF and elsewhere can be used individually to achieve the same results.
>
> During this article we will use the [Android Hide Secrets](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) research repository that is a dummy mobile app with API keys hidden using several different techniques.

Another alternative to extract secrets is to perfome a Man in the Middle (MitM) attack to intercept the TLS connection and extract all secrets and learn how the mobile app interacts with the backend and any other third party APIs, and you can see how I done it in the article
[Steal that Api Key with a Man in the Middle Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack):

> In order to help to demonstrate how to steal an API key, I have built and released in Github the [Currency Converter Demo](https://github.com/approov/currency-converter-demo/tree/0.1.1) app for Android, which uses the same [JNI/NDK](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni) technique we used in the earlier [Android Hide Secrets](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/src/main/java/com/criticalblue/androidhidesecrets/MainActivity.java#L37-L41) app to [hide the API key](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/ed0217325d42be480a15c003fae9f201ee0f3f88/app/src/main/cpp/api_key.h.example).
>
> So, in this article you will learn how to setup and run a MitM attack to intercept https traffic in a mobile device under your control, so that you can steal the API key. Finally, you will see at a high level how MitM attacks can be mitigated.

Wait, I imagine you now thinking, but I will use certificate pinning to protect my TLS channel, no problem just see how certificate pinning can be easily bypassed in a device the attacker controls in the article [Bypassing Certificate Pinning](https://blog.approov.io/bypassing-certificate-pinning)

> In this article you will learn how to repackage a mobile app in order to disable certificate pinning and in the process you will also learn how to create an Android emulator with a writable system to allow for adding the custom certificate authority for the proxy server into the Android operating system trust store. This will allow us to bypass certificate pinning and intercept the requests between the mobile and its backend with a MitM attack.

While repackaging a mobile app to bypass pinning is a good solution my preference goes to do it dynamically at runtime as I show in the article [How to Bypass Certificate Pinning with Frida on an Android App](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-bypass-certificate-pinning-with-frida-on-an-android-app):

> Today I will show how to use the Frida instrumentation framework to hook into the mobile app at runtime and instrument the code in order to perform a successful MitM attack even when the mobile app has implemented certificate pinning.

> Bypassing certificate pinning is not too hard, just a little laborious, and allows an attacker to understand in detail how a mobile app communicates with its API, and then use that same knowledge to automate attacks or build other services around it.

Now you may be thinking that you have lost the battle and shouldn't care about adding protections because they will end-up to be bypassed. Well, I have to tell you that software security shares the same traits as the defences in the medieval castles, where they used it in layers, in order to make the assault to the castle as hard as possible, and hopefully impossible. So, you need to adopt the same posture as them and put as many security layers as you can afford, and required by law, in order to make the attackers efforts time consuming and to require more expertise then most of them may have.

### YOUR QUESTIONS

> In order to overcome this, I was thinking of designing my Login API, so that rather than having an accessToken and a refreshToken in the payload response of the API, the Login API will issue a 301 Redirect on myapp://some-path?accessToken=X&refreshToken=Y. This will ensure that if a phishing app is calling my APIs, the accessToken and the refreshToken are sent to the original APP.
>
> Is this a correct approach?

So, I think that by now is obvious that your solution will not be effective and will be easily defeated with repackaging the mobile app, MitM attack it or simply by instrumenting the code at runtime.

> If not, which design would be suggested?

You should use a security approach where the API backend is able to recognize that **what** is making the request is indeed a genuine and untampered/repacked/cloned version of your mobile app, not just **who** is making the request, as when user authentication is solely used to protect unauthorised access to an API.

#### The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

I wrote a series of articles around API and Mobile security, and in the article [Why Does Your Mobile App Need An Api Key?](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key#api-who-vs-what) you can read in detail the difference between **who** and **what** is accessing your API server, but I will extract here the main takes from it:

> The **what** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of your mobile app, or is it a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?

> The **who** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

So think about the **who** as the user your API server will be able to Authenticate and Authorize access to the data, and think about the **what** as the software making that request in behalf of the user.

### POSSIBLE SOLUTION

I recommend you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605789/6454622) I gave to the question *How to secure an API REST for mobile app?*, especially the sections *Hardening and Shielding the Mobile App*, *Securing the API Server* and *A Possible Better Solution*.

You will see that you can use a plethora of defence layers, like in medieval castles, and that the solution you may want to employ, to guarantee with an high degree of confidence that **what** is doing the request to the backend is indeed your genuine mobile app, is the Mobile App Attestation.

#### Do You Want To Go The Extra Mile?

In any response to a security question I always like to reference the excellent work from the OWASP foundation.

##### For APIS

[OWASP API Security Top 10](https://github.com/OWASP/API-Security)

> The OWASP API Security Project seeks to provide value to software developers and security assessors by underscoring the potential risks in insecure APIs, and illustrating how these risks may be mitigated. In order to facilitate this goal, the OWASP API Security Project will create and maintain a Top 10 API Security Risks document, as well as a documentation portal for best practices when creating or assessing APIs.

##### For Mobile Apps

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

[OWASP - Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg):

> The Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG) is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security development, testing and reverse engineering.